# Computed hegiht does not equall to the actuall height of the element

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

quick css question,
I have a div, and I am setting its height to 80px [image]

But, when I look at the computed styles tab in chrome dev tools the height is actually 79.9884px, am I screwing something, or it just the default behavior of a browser?
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Dear @Michael can you provide your HTML structure?, So we can quickly fixed your issue.

Comment: Your border height is part of your total height

Comment: On setting box-sizing: border-box; border and padding will share the height defined for the content. If you applied box-sizing: border-box; on the root element or universal selector than it will be applied on all the elements. But here still on sum up of border and content it's not exactly 80px it's 79.9884px.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]

Comment: hey guis, I did not change a thing, refreshed the page and now it's 80px... Superweird!